# Using TCL to remove a variable

Tags: sql, tcl

I'm tring to remove cerain usernames from a list if there count value is 0 so that only the users with a count of greater than 0 will appear. I've tried several methods without success so I'm hoping for some pointers in the right direction

```
if {![mysqlsel $db_handle "
    SELECT `crew`.`user`,IF(`count`,`count`,0) AS count 
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT `user` FROM `crew`) AS crew 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT `user`,COUNT(`user`) AS count 
        FROM `info` 
        WHERE `timestamp` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP((LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
        GROUP BY `user`) AS info 
    ON crew.user = info.user $refine 
    ORDER BY `count` DESC
"]} then {
    putnow "PRIVMSG $chan_(kadd) :No results found\."
    return 0
}

mysqlmap $db_handle {user count} {
    if { $count >= $quota_(amount) || $user != "somename" } {
        putnow "PRIVMSG $chan_(kadd) : \[\00314[num [incr place]]\003\] \00314$user\003 is \0033PASSiNG\003 \00314>\003 \00303$count mile(s) this month\003"
    } else {
        putnow "PRIVMSG $chan_(kadd) : \[\00314[num [incr place]]\003\] \00314$user\003 is \0034FAiLiNG\003 \00314>\003 \00304$count mile(s) this month\003"
    }
}
```

Comment: It would seem like some sort of `WHERE` clause on the outer part of the query would be the right approach. (I redid the formatting because reading a query that long on one line is _difficult_ and headache-inducing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While moving filtering into the query is the right approach here, you can also do it on the Tcl side since I'd bet very good money that `mysqlmap` follows the standard Tcl looping result code conventions:

```
mysqlmap $db_handle {user count} {
    if {$count == 0} { 
        # Skip this one entirely
        continue
    }
    if { $count >= $quota_(amount) || $user != "somename" } {
        putnow "PRIVMSG $chan_(kadd) : \[\00314[num [incr place]]\003\] \00314$user\003 is \0033PASSiNG\003 \00314>\003 \00303$count mile(s) this month\003"
    } else {
        putnow "PRIVMSG $chan_(kadd) : \[\00314[num [incr place]]\003\] \00314$user\003 is \0034FAiLiNG\003 \00314>\003 \00304$count mile(s) this month\003"
    }
}
```

---

Without any testing, here's how the query might get the filter added.

```
if {![mysqlsel $db_handle "
    SELECT `crew`.`user`, `info`.`count` AS `count`
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT `user` FROM `crew`) AS `crew` 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT `user`, COUNT(`user`) AS `count` 
        FROM `info` 
        WHERE `timestamp` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP((LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
        GROUP BY `user`) AS `info` 
    ON `crew`.`user` = `info`.`user`
    WHERE `count` > 0                         -- <<< This line here <<<
    $refine 
    ORDER BY `count` DESC
"]} then {
    putnow "PRIVMSG $chan_(kadd) :No results found\."
    return 0
}
```

You'll need to adjust the `$refine` clause generation to account for the fact that there's always a `WHERE` in front of it. (Also, you are aware that it's a potential SQL injection vector? Surfacing any form of complex querying to users is always potentially tricky as with great power comes great opportunity for abuse.)

Comment: If this query were being run at all frequently, it'd be worth building a view…